# ls: grep files with name pattern into one line

Tags: bash, unix, grep, ls

I have some files that start with a prefix, which I will call `p_` in this context. Let's say I have three files with the prefix named `p_1`, `p_2`, `p_3`. How do I grep a list of these files through something like GNU ls into one space-separated string?

Example:

```
$ ls | grep p_
p_1 <\
p_2 < --- Remove '\n' after the file name and replace with space
p_3 </

# So that we get...
$ ls [.. solution goes here ..]
p_1 p_2 p_3
```

Now say, if we want to `rm` all files with the prefix, we can use:

```
$ rm $(ls [.. solution goes here ..])
```

Which will be the same as:

```
$ rm p_1 p_2 p_3
```

Comment: why not simply using `rm p_*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `| xargs echo`:

```
$ rm $(ls | grep p_ | xargs echo)
```

Or more directly, `| xargs rm`:

```
$ ls | grep p_ | xargs rm
```

Or even more directly, since arguments can be separated by any whitespace, which includes newlines:

```
$ rm $(ls | grep p_)
```

I personally like globbing:

```
$ rm p_*
```

Comment: Thank you! Never knew any whitespace could work for command arguments.  **EDIT**: globs, doh!

Answer (score 2):

```
ls p_*
```

and you could also do

```
rm p_*
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward rm `p_*` should work to remove all files starting with `p_`.

To display files starting with `p_`, you could use `ls p_*`. You can also use `ls -l` or `-a` options with `p_*` to view other details of these files.